# Cannot load a texture to AssetManager in libGDX

Tags: libgdx

I seem to be unable to properly load a texture from the "assets" folder in my libgdx project in Eclipse.
My code is:

```
AssetManager am = new AssetManager();
am.load("football.png", Texture.class);
if(! am.isLoaded("football.png")) System.out.println("NOT loaded");
```

The "assets" folder is in the "/my-gdx-game-android", whereas the code above is called from the "/my-gdx-game-core/src/com/mygdx/game/MyGdxGame.java".
I am absolutely sure the texture is there. However, I am constantly getting "NOT loaded" message. Obviously, I am doing something wrong here. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turns out that AssetManager loads assets asynchronously. To get rid of the "NOT loaded" message, I had to put

```
am.finishLoading();
```

before

```
if(! am.isLoaded("football.png")) System.out.println("NOT loaded");
```

This method blocks the thread until all assets are loaded.